# How good is the Nikon 70-300mm lens that comes along with the Nikon D5600?

Tags: lens

I'm planning to buy a new camera (Nikon D5600) and it turns out that they have two variants. One of the variants come with the usual 18-55mm lens and a 70-300mm telephoto lens. The build as per me, as I've seen it, was perfectly fine to me. No issues with that. I want to know from all the photographers out there regarding it's quality and focussing speed.

[I'm talking about this lens model.](https://www.amazon.in/Nikon-4-5-6-3G-ED-VR-Cameras/dp/B01KJ8UMKK/ref=asc_df_B01KJ8UMKK/?tag=googleshopmob-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397132050152&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=752212229569391299&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9040196&hvtargid=pla-318315515426&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi)

P.S. : I'm a high school student who has taken up a more-than-amateur interest in photography and is self-taught. I can't afford to buy costly lenses now, so suggest me if the 70-300mm lens is worth the price for a beginner or not.

Comment: You can [compare](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=622&Camera=614&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=738&Sample=0&CameraComp=963&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0) lenses at The Digital Picture. Whether a lens is worth the price is a matter of personal opinion. Have you considered mirrorless cameras with adapters and vintage lenses? There are old primes that produce very nice images for much less than their modern equivalents. The trade off is having to control focus and aperture manually.

Comment: I had considered the sony a6000 but later discarded the choice as the camera is too old. Nikon D5600 is relatively new. Moreover the sony mirrorless is a tad bit out of budget now and the lenses are also a bit more costly than nikkor. I don't think I can fund that much, atleast for the time-being. And yes! I know about the old primes, that's not a trade off for me ;)

Comment: You're more likely to benefit by getting the extra lens with the kit.  It'll let you try the longer focal lengths, and likely cost less as part of the kit than separately.  With the mirrorless route, you could start with the kit lens, then forego native lenses for "vintage".  28mm, 50mm, and 135mm lenses tend to be pretty inexpensive.  Add a focal reducer, and they can serve double duty (0.72x).

Comment: Thank you so much mate! Cleared my doubts!

Comment: Technologically, the D5600 appears to be older than the Sony a6000 in many aspects.

Comment: However, the lens is kind of TOO NEW - that is an AF-P lens, which can land you in a dead end if you ever decide to go cross-system - it is incompatible with manual adapters and many older Nikon cameras! AF-S lenses might be a better suit for you.

Comment: Actually my main limitation is the budget issue. Sony lenses come at roughly $350 while nikkor lenses, being more common, are available at $210. Moreover, here in India, i can get nikonD5600 plus the two lenses at $700. The sony a6000, I understand is more modern, but the kit lens of sony, as I've heard is not good. So it seems I've to shell out extra money to get same quality image that Nikon yields in $700.

Comment: It's just for the present moment. I'll start my mbbs studies where I'll get internship money, and with that I'm definitely gonna upgrade my gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If including the telephoto kit lens in the camera kit is the only way you can afford a telephoto lens, then the lens in question is better than any other option you have for owning a telephoto lens.

In general, a two lens 18-55mm plus 70-300mm kit with a camera body is a pretty good deal that allows one to buy the body and two lenses for less than the individual pieces would cost if bought separately. Sometimes, if available, an 18-55mm plus 55-200mm or 55-250mm kit is [a better option for an APS-C camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94810/15871) than an 18-55mm plus 70-300mm kit. You'll also usually [spend less and get better overall image quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38741/15871) with an 18-55mm plus 55-250mm or 70-300mm combo than with something like an 18-200mm or 18-300mm "all-in-one" lens.

The 70-300mm f/4-5.6 is not a stellar lens that will challenge zoom lenses five times its price, but then neither are any other 70-300/f/4-5.6 lenses in the same class and price range. **But it can still get you a lot closer to shots you could get with a more costly lens than no lens at all will.**