# Canon EOS 550D vs Canon EOS Rebel XSi for Bird Photography &/or UW Surf Photography

Tags: equipment-recommendation, underwater, bird-photography

I realize these are both novice type cameras, but I got them for free and appear to be forever on a budget.

I am curious which camera body I should invest the money in to get into the subjects of photography I most enjoy.

I really want to get into Bird photography and buy various long lenses. (recs on long lenses?)

I also want to delve into Underwater surf photography and purchase an Underwater housing unit. (recs on underwater surf housing units?)

Please any comments, insights and recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you and much love,

George

(Currently residing in the South Bay Area.)

Comment: [Letter to George](https://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2010/05/letter-to-george.html)

Comment: You may want to mention your budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few differences between either camera, other than sensor resolution and video capability. They're both from the same series of cameras within Canon's product line.

The Canon EOS 550D was marketed in North America as the Canon EOS Rebel T2i when it was introduced in early 2010.

The Canon EOS 450D was marketed in North America as the Canon EOS Rebel XSi when it was introduced in mid 2008.

Between those two models, there was the Canon EOS 500D/Rebel T1i introduced in early 2009.

The lens pool for both cameras is exactly the same. Any lens that works with the Rebel XSi/450D also works with the Rebel T2i/550d and vice-versa.

The Rebel XSi/450D has a 12.2 MP sensor with a pixel pitch of 5.2µm.

The Rebel T1i/550D has an 18 MP sensor with a pixel pitch of 4.3µm. This is the same basic sensor introduced in the EOS 7D in 2009 and used in various Canon APS-C cameras for much of the decade between 2010-2020.

The Rebel XSi/450D did not have video capability as shipped from Canon. However, Canon's *EOS Utility 2* and third party software can be used to output Live View video from the camera that can be recorded by a tethered computer (but not internally in the camera). That's not of much use out in the field shooting birds or surfing, rather than in a studio, though. The Rebel T2i/550D has built-in video capabilities that can record directly to the memory card.

> I really want to get into Bird photography and buy various long lenses. (recs on long lenses?)

and

> I also want to delve into Underwater surf photography and purchase an Underwater housing unit. (recs on underwater surf housing units?)

**For birding**, focal length is pretty much everything. No matter how much you spend, it never seems to be enough. More focal length and wider maximum aperture also tend to get fairly expensive very quickly. In general, you get what you pay for with telephoto zoom lenses.

- Canon's [EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III is cheap](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35171/15871), but probably not even worth what it costs.
- The lowest priced third party 70-300mm f/4-5.6 lenses are not the greatest in the world, but if they're all you can afford [they're better than no lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114052/15871) in the 70-300mm focal length range.
- Be sure any third party lens you are considering is up to date with whatever camera you're using. [Older third party lenses can have compatibility issues with newer camera bodies](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83122/15871) that didn't exist when the third party manufacturer reverse engineered their lenses to work with existing cameras. I've got an EF mount Sigma 70-300mm from the 1990s that works fine on my old EOS film bodies, but it locks up any of my EOS digital bodies (the oldest is a Rebel XTi/400D) when the aperture is set to anything other than wide open. For the two cameras in question, any lens model or updated version released after 2010 should be fine.
- For cameras with "cropped" APS-C sensors, such as the two you've mentioned, any of the [EF-S 55-250mm lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95279/15871) can be a good value. They're optically about as good as Canon's consumer grade EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 lenses, but around half the cost. Of course [you give up 50mm at the long end](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/94827/15871).

**For getting in the water** with surfers pretty much any lower budget solution will fit both cameras. By the time you're considering a customised housing for either camera that can't be used with the other, you're in a price range much higher than what both cameras combined are worth.

**My recommendation would be to use both cameras.** Most accessories and all lenses that work with one will also work with the other. The main exception would be the batteries, which do differ between the two camera bodies. [Higher quality third party batteries](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/34791/15871) are pretty affordable, though.

- Hang your longest focal length lens on the Rebel T2i/550D and use it for birding and shooting surfers from the beach. The higher 18 MP sensor resolution will allow you to crop a little more than you could with the 12MP Rebel XSi/450D.
- Use the Rebel XSi/450D with an 18-55mm kit lens that came with most Rebel/xx0D camera bodies for the wet stuff. The larger pixel pitch of the 12.2 MP sensor *might* give you a *little bit* better low light performance under water. On the other hand, the newer DiG!C 4 image processing chip used in the Rebel T2i/550D may more than make up the difference compared to the older DiG!C III processor used by the Rebel XSi/450D. The difference in DiG!C processing chips would apply mainly to direct-from-camera JPEGs. For raw files, the larger pixels should make a difference when images from both cameras are converted using the same external applications.

If you lose the older body and cheap kit lens due to water damage, it won't sting as bad as losing the newer body and any more expensive lens(es) you might buy.

As far as various versions of Canon's EF-S 18-55mm lenses go, the IS variations tend to have better quality control than the older non-IS versions. (The EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 II that came with my Rebel XTi/400D was pretty bad, with a spot left of center that was always soft, no matter what aperture or focus distance was used.) The general consensus is that the IS versions, which are based on a very similar optical formula, were more carefully screened before being allowed to ship from the factory.

Comment: Michael C, you are awsome for offering such detailed advice! : D

Answer (score 1):

The XSi is also known as the 450D. The 550D being its successor has slightly better characteristics (18MPX vs 12, a bit more ISO), but the game changer is that the 550D can do video. They are otherwise fairly similar cameras.

Answer (score 1):

> I am curious which camera body I should invest the money in to get into the subjects of photography I most enjoy.

I used to own a [550D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_550D). It's a reasonable camera to use if you already have one or if that's all you can afford, but I wouldn't recommend buying or dumping money into one or an older model, such as the [450D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_450D).

Both cameras use the same EF/EF-S lenses. So if you decide to stay with Canon bodies, you'll be able to use any lens you purchase with either body or future crop-sensor DSLRs. You can also use EF lenses with adapter on Canon mirrorless cameras.

> I really want to get into Bird photography and buy various long lenses. (recs on long lenses?)

Consider starting with a telephoto zoom. Some options to consider.

- EF-S 55-250/4-5.6 IS II/STM/USM/ETC. I've used an IS II variant. Optics are good, but construction is cheap. Even the mount is plastic. If it had a metal mount, I'd recommend it without reservation, but with the plastic mount, I suggest considering other options if they're within your budget.
- EF 70-200/2.8 L IS II/III USM is considered among the best in image quality and has matched teleconverters to extend reach. Price and weight are high.
- EF 70-300/4-5.6 IS II USM (consumer-level lens). This is the second lens Canon has released with "nano USM". In reasonably good lighting, focus is much slower than conventional USM. There's also occasional hunting and missed focus. Images are very good when it nails focus.
- EF 70-300/4.5-5.6 DO IS USM is undervalued, currently costing less than the consumer-level EF 70-300/4-5.6 IS II USM. The DO lens is built and handles better than the consumer lens. Focus is fast and consistent, but the aperture is slower at the short end. It softens at the long end, but a bit of sharpening takes care of it. It's smaller and lighter than similar lenses.
- EF 70-300/4-5.6 L IS USM is also undervalued because it doesn't perform as well as the 70-200/2.8. It performs better than the other 70-300 lenses, but it weighs and costs more (but only about 20-25%).

Third party options:

- Tamron 70-200/2.8 G2 – Focus speed and accuracy of the  copy I tried was poor. I didn't have enough usable images to evaluate sharpness. For used copies, an EF 70-200/2.8 L IS II costs only about 25% more. For budget, 70-300/4-5.6 L costs about 35% less.
- Sigma 70-200/2.8 Sports – Haven't tried this lens. Costs more than some used copies of 70-200/2.8 L II.

"Buy cheap, buy twice." Consider choosing one of the Canon L lenses. They are among the top performing lenses. Their prices aren't too high on the used market, and they are less likely to have compatibility issues if you switch to a different Canon DSLR or mirrorless camera.

> I also want to delve into Underwater surf photography and purchase an Underwater housing unit. (recs on underwater surf housing units?)

Consider purchasing a waterproof compact camera.

I'm not brave enough to risk damaging or losing an expensive camera and lens in the ocean. Underwater housings are often expensive and camera specific. There are cheaper underwater bags, but they seem better suited for protection against the elements than bona fide use under water.

Comment: Either you got the best copy of the 70-300mm DO ever sold or some really bad copies of the 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS II. No reviewer/tester I've ever seen said the 70-300mm DO is better than the older conventional 70-300mm lenses. Most say it is noticeably worse but that its one redeeming attribute is the compact size which allows it to be carried into venues (sports stadiums, entertainment venues, etc) where the longer conventional lenses are not allowed for ticket buying spectators without media credentials.

Comment: Since OP stated he's "forever on a budget", it might be better to look for third party lenses instead of Canon only. You can get the Tamron 70-200/2.8 G2 for roughly half of what the Canon one costs, and it's not that far off. The 150-600mm might be an option too, but I haven't tested that one yet.

Comment: DO vs IS II – IS II is sharper at focal lengths > 200mm *if* it nails focus, but it's motors are slow, it hunts, and still misses focus. DO focuses faster and consistently hits focus. The build is significantly better. It's softer at the long end, but a bit of sharpening takes care of it.

Comment: Canon sensors (in 450D and 550D) intentionally blur images, so lens softness is partially caused by the sensor. Reviews panning the lens are why it's undervalued and *cheap* on the used market. For someone on a budget, it's a reasonable option to *consider*. If budget isn't a concern, EF 70-200/2.8 L IS III USM is a better choice.

Comment: @Dynat Focus speed and accuracy of the Tamron 70-200/2.8 G2 that I tried was poor. AF performance was so poor that I didn't have enough usable images to evaluate sharpness against other lenses. For used copies, an EF 70-200/2.8 L IS II costs only about 25% more. For budget, 70-300/4-5.6 L costs about 35% less.

Comment: @xiota Huh, weird. Reviews usually praise the AF, and mine works fine - on concerts nonetheless, where it's the norm that lighting is "suboptimal".

Comment: @Dynat Might have been bad copies. Was using store rental copies. The EF 24-105/4 L IS II USM was also performing miserably that day. Using poorly performing versions of coveted lenses is a good way to clear up GAS.